# Flutter SliverToBoxAdapter which fits child size

Tags: flutter

I want to create a scrollable content which include:

1. A header widget that includes several child widgets - which it's height is unknown
2. A list of rows widgets

[image]

The correct way to do that is using a **CustomScrollView**, like this:

```
Widget _buildView(BuildContext context) {
return  (
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        height: 128.0,
        child: _buildHeader(context),
      ),
    ),
    _buildList(context),
  ],
);
```

}

My problem is that my unlike this code sample, my header's height is unknown, and should fit its children's height (which can change).

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Sliver needs to adapt on the header's height, you can consider using [ConstrainedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConstrainedBox-class.html) on your header. Depending on your use case, you can set a `minHeight` and `maxHeight` to let the viewport know the widget's size to be rendered.